# A Corollary from Burton's Elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a corollary from page 160 of Burton Elementary number theory.

**Corollary**. If $p$ is an odd prime, then $p^2$ has a primitive root; in fact, for a primitive root $r$ of $p$, either $r$ or $r + p$ (or both) is a primitive root of $p^2$.

**Proof**. The assertion is almost obvious: If $r$ is a primitive root of $p$, then $\color{red}{\text{the order of $r$ modulo $p^2$ is either $p- 1$ or $p(p- 1) = \phi(p^2 )$}}$. The foregoing proof shows that if $r$ has order $p - 1$ modulo $p^2$, then $r + p$ is a primitive root of $p^2$.

Why the order of $r$ modulo $p^2$ is either $p- 1$ or $p(p- 1) = \phi(p^2 )$? I think it's can be $p$ and also $d$ such that $d|p-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d$ be the order of $r$ (mod $p^2$). $r^d=1$ (mod $p^2$), so $r^d=1$ (mod $p$) as well and because $r$ is a primitive root, $(p-1)$ must divide $d$. Since $d$ divides $p(p-1)$ and $p$ is prime, $d$ must be either $(p-1)$ or $p(p-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$r$ wasn't just a random unit modulo $p^2$: $r$ was chosen so that it is a primitive root modulo $p$ which puts a constraint on the possible values modulo $p^2$ that we may choose.

Answer (score 1):

since $r$ is primitive mod $p$, it follows that $r^d$ is not zero mod $p$,  hence also not mod $p^2$, for any proper divisor $d$ of $p-1$ and for $d=p$. Hence the order of $r$ must be (as a divisor of $p(p-1)$) either $p-1$ or $p(p-1)$.